# Difference in applied base colour and view port also render image is totally different

Tags: rendering, 3d-view

I am new to blender and 3d applications I have done my first low poly building

[image]

[image]

[image]

As you can see I have created a building and copied but some of the objects are showing black colour and my final output render is also totally different from viewport.

Comment: did you check your face orientation? if yes, pls provide blend file because you didn't give us enough useful information to check it out

Comment: there are 4 modes in the viewport, are you sure that you've selected the Rendered mode, and that you see the world and lights of the viewport? As for the black objects, it may be because these objects are overlapping with duplications, overlapping faces can create a black surface

Comment: Sorry guys , i have checked the face orientation and it has so many inverted normals i tried to flip those by selecting all and recalculate outside and inside but nothing seems works , i have merged the duplicate vertices but still in face orientation there are so many inverted normals

Comment: the black faces are probably due to overlapping faces, not inverted normals. The faces maybe overlapping within the same object or it may be another object. Please share your file (at least one object), pack the images if you use some.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead, see [How to take a screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org). Photos are harder to read, because we have to guess if we are looking at a external interference like reflections or smudges or Moiré patterns, hardware issues such as a malfunctioning display or connection, a software level bug or driver malfunction, or an or actual artifact or issue with the model itself.

Comment: Please add details into your original question by editing it, don't post information in the comments